# SNOWFLAKE : Constraint on table that doesn't exists

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use INFORMATON_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS in a stored procedure to dynamically generate a uniqueness check on the tables.
It works fine until I have a constraint that refers to a table that does not exist or no longer exists.

Have you ever been confronted with this situation? Is there a way to clean the information_schema

thanks

Comment: information_schema.table_constraints will not return rows related to a dropped table. 
is it possible the table was dropped mid-process?

Answer (score 0):

Join to SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES, you'll find column DELETED there, use it for filtering.

Comment: Just be mindful of the latency on account_usage. Which on this view can be up to 90 min. 

information_schema is real-time. If an object is dropped, it will not appear in information_schema.table_constraints.